# Why EF trim milliseconds in Time and DateTime values

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, datetime

I've ADO.NET Entity Data Model generated from SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and in my table I've Time or Datetime value. In datagrid this fields shows correctly with milliseconds, but in LINQ query with my ObjectSet<> I've a lost of milliseconds. Why?

```
var query = from data in ctx.Data
            join member in ctx.Members
            on data.MemberId equals member.MemberId
            where member.StepId == (int)RepStepCombo.SelectedValue
            orderby data.Time ascending
            select new { 
                data.LaneNum, 
                member.MemberName, 
                data.Time, 
                mill = data.Time.Millisecond
            };

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("text.txt");
foreach (var data in query)
{
    sw.WriteLine(data.LaneNum + " " + 
                 data.MemberName + " " + " millisec: " +
                 data.Time.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff") + " " + 
                 data.mill);
}
sw.Close();
sw.Dispose();
```

Comment: What output line contains? You don't see milliseconds both at `fff` format and in `mill` property? What you see in debugger for `Time` property?

Comment: In output I see 2 name1 millisec: 00:01:03.000 0
1 name2 millisec: 00:01:04.000 0

Comment: No, I've made some changes in milliseconds and save to db, than I see in SSMS changes in this values

Comment: What type column has in database?

Comment: DateTime and I try Time - in both milliseconds 0 in LINQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you sure Time is DateTime and not SmallDateTime? SmallDateTime has a smaller resolution and is not ms precise.

I have no problem getting milliseconds from a datetime field with Sql2008 and EF:

```
var members = from s in myEntites.TableName
              select s;

            foreach (TableEntry entry in members)
            {
                String time = ((DateTime)entry.date).ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");
                Console.WriteLine(time);
            }
```

for time, convert to TimeSpan:

```
    var members = from s in myEntites.TableName
                  where s.myTime != null
                  select s;

    foreach (Entity myEntity in members)
    {
        String time = ((TimeSpan)myEntity.myTime).Milliseconds.ToString();
    }
```

"works on my machine!" :)

Comment: In Database I've field of type Time(2) named Time. And how to get work your code for SQL Server type Time and EF type Time?

Comment: convert your "Time" to .NET TimeSpan

Comment: Try more hard LINQ, such grouping and join - and you will lose milliseconds of TimeSpan

Comment: have you actually tried this? can't imagine a Join removes milliseconds from the query result... that would be a bug in the framework :)

Comment: E.g. try with select new, and your TimeSpan will lose milliseconds